# Problem with routes when migrating oData 7.5.0 to oData 8.1.1

Tags: .net, routes, migration, odata

In Net Core 3.1 and oData 7.5.0

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[Route("categories/{categoryId}/elements")]
[ODataRoute("categories/{categoryId}/elements")]
public Task<IQueryable<CategoryElement>> QueryActiveElementsByCategoryIdAsync(int categoryId)
{
  return this.processor.QueryAllAsync<CategoryElement>(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId && c.IsActive == true);
}
```

[Code Api Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD0Hu.png)
Result
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f13z8.png)

In Net 6 and oData 8.1.1

```cs
[HttpGet("categories/{categoryId}/elements")]
[EnableQuery]
[TrueAuthorize(Role.Administrator)]
public Task<IQueryable<CategoryElement>> QueryActiveElementsByCategoryIdAsync(int categoryId)
{
  return this.processor.QueryAllAsync<CategoryElement>(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId && c.IsActive == true);
}
```

[Code Api Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zfqs.png)
Result
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVTDy.png)

Therefore the expected result is not compatible with the Front